# Is it possible to check on entries in a table in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is a bit unclear in the title so here is the scenario:

Suppose there is a table that holds entries of activities performed by commission agents. So if an Agent A comes to office his entry would be made in the table. Similarly for other agents as well:

`Agent Status
 A     Absent
 B     Out for collection
 C     Job completed
 D     Job completed
 E     Job completed
 F     Job completed`

Now in above table lets say A, B and C are in one team (Team ABC) and D, E and F are in one team (Team DEF). Is it possible to write a SQL query which returns the status of the team. 
For eg in above table D, E and F completed their jobs so for their team, team status should be Completed while for Team ABC it should be Uncompleted as one of their members was absent while other just went out for collection.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `team` defined? In another table? Also the condition of `Uncompleted` is not all `Job completed`?

Comment: There must be a table which shows which Agents belong to which Team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a column which have a `team` for each `player`, you can do something like below

```
  select team,
  case 
  when count(*)
       =
       sum(case
          when status='Job completed'
              then 1 
              else 0 
          end
          ) 
  then 'COMPLETED' 
    else 'UNCOMPLETED' 
  end as status
  from table1 
  group by team
```

If `team` is coming from a different table, then first join that with your table and then use this resultset in the main query, something like

```
with table1 as 
(select a.agent,a.status,t.team 
from agent a 
inner join team t
on a.agent=t.agent)
select team, case .... --rest of the query.
```

Here is an extended example with your resultset

```
  with table1(Agent,Status,Team) as (
  select 'A','Absent','ABC' from dual union all
  select 'B','Out for collection','ABC' from dual union all
  select 'C','Job completed','ABC' from dual union all
  select 'D','Job completed','DEF' from dual union all
  select 'E','Job completed','DEF' from dual union all
  select 'F','Job completed','DEF' from dual)
   select team,
  case 
  when count(*)
       =
       sum(case
          when status='Job completed'
              then 1 
              else 0 
          end
          ) 
  then 'COMPLETED' 
    else 'UNCOMPLETED' 
  end as status
  from table1 
  group by team
```

Output

```
Team Status
DEF  COMPLETED
ABC  UNCOMPLETED
```